# Appending to Query if not null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm still trying to work my way around learning .net MVC, and everyone has been helpful so far here, which this newbie appreciates.

When I submit a form, the user has the option to only search within set categories or subcategories.  Right now I have the form set up so each checkbox has the same name, i.e.:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="Category Name" />
```

When I pass the form data to the controller, I read that I should use something like:

```
string[] category
```

And this will create a comma separated array of the values that were checked.

Now when I get to the query portion in the controller, I first check to see if the array is not null or length is 0, i.e.:

```
if ((category != null) || (category.Count() > 0))
```

Now my question is how can I check for each category in the query?  Meaning something like:

```
var results = db.Employees.Join(db.Category, e => e.ID, c => c.EmployeeID, (e, c) => new { e = e, c = c }).Where(c => c.Name.Equals(category1) || c.Name.Equals(category2));
```

Is it possible to build the full query like building a string in C#/.Net MVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you plan to search in a collection, create a `Hashset<string>` for the Category Name as follows:

```
var categoryHashset = new HashSet<string> {"","Category2",..,"CategoryN"};
Or
var categoryHashset = new HashSet<string>(CategoryList);
```

Now Check using Contains method, which has O(1) performance in this case. Here Performance is important when Category collection size increase.

```
categoryHashset.Contains("Category1")
```

Your query will become:

```
var results = db.Employees.Join(db.Category, e => e.ID, c => c.EmployeeID, (e, c) => new { e = e, c = c })
                          .Where(c => categoryHashset.Contains(c.Name));
```

Comment: Hi Mrinal, I am getting this error: `{"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Contains[String](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[System.String], System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer1[System.String])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}` for the portion when I am counting the total results.

Comment: Please use Without `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`, this one needs an extension method which i will update shortly

Comment: Please check the Updated version, I have realized that for `Hashset<string>`, since it creates a unique `Hash` even Case matters, thus using `StringComparer`, will not allow it to remain O(1), since I have to use Any operator to scan through, thus making it O(N)

Comment: Looks like the search is working as the results match a direct query.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.Contains()` method of an `IEnumerable` so that for each category, it will check if the name is contained in the provided list of categories.

If you have the categories in the `category` array, then you can update your query to:

```
var results = db.Employees.Join(db.Category, e => e.ID, c => c.EmployeeID, (e, c) => new { e = e, c = c })
                          .Where(c => category.Contains(c.Name));
```

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I was overthinking it with category being an array.

Comment: Standard `IEnumerable` **Contains** is not optimized for search, it does the O(N) linear search, ideally data structures like `Hashset, Dictionary, LookUp `are meant for quick O(1) search